# Javascript not working as I want to

Tags: javascript, html

Alright, I have made some JavaScript for an assessment. Everything worked fine until I put in a new function with a `switch` statement called:

```
function differentComments(answer) {
```

The program doesn't seem to load the follow function anymore when the function differentComments is in there:

```
function genQuestion() {
```

All of my JavaScript code is below (HTML is [available on Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/hqD7fh5a)):

```
var x, y; //the global variables

function aNumber() {
    return Math.floor(1 + Math.random() * 12);
}

function genQuestion()  {
    x = aNumber();
    y = aNumber();

    dout = document.getElementById('Question');
    dout.value = x + " times " + y;
}

function buttonPressed() {
    var input = document.getElementById('Typed').value;
    var answer = x * y;

    if (input == answer) {
        differentComments("Right");
        genQuestion();
    } else {
        differentComments("Wrong");
    }

    document.getElementById('Typed').value="";
}

function differentComments(answer)  {
    var random_number = Math.floor(1 + Math.random() * 4);

    if (answer == "Right")  {
        switch (random_number) {
        case 1:
            window.alert("Very Good!");
            break;
        case 2:
            window.alert("Excellent!");
            break;
        case 3:
            window.alert("Correct - Nice work!");
            break;
        case 4:
            window.alert("Correct - keep up the good work!");
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

    } else (answer == "Wrong") {
        switch (random_number) {
        case 1:
            window.alert("No. Please try again.");
            break;
        case 2:
            window.alert("Wrong. Try once more.");
            break;
        case 3:
            window.alert("Incorrect – Don’t give up.");
            break;
        case 4:
            window.alert("No – keep trying.");
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read [How to ask programming questions?](http://codingkilledthecat.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/how-to-ask-for-programming-help/).

Comment: Welcome to [so]. It's better to provide the code directly, instead of simply posting a link elsewhere. For more information on asking questions, see [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your else clause is incorrect.

```
        if (answer == "Right")  {
                switch(random_number)   {
                   ...
                }
        else (answer == "Wrong") {
        }
```

won't parse because the second test is missing an if.

```
        if (answer == "Right")  {
                switch(random_number)   {
                   ...
                }
        else **if** (answer == "Wrong") {
        }
```

Essentially you're treating an if() as if it's a switch(), and that's not syntactically correct.

The first thing you should do when you run into situations like this is use either jshint or jslint to check the syntactical correctness of your code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was surprised I didn't notice that tiny mistake.

Answer (score 1):

In your code block :

```
if (answer == "Right")  {
      switch(random_number)   {
           ...
      }
else (answer == "Wrong") {
      switch(random_number)   {
           ...
      }
}
```

mean you put `if and else` statement and a else condition only execute when all if conditions are return `false`. So there is no need to put conditional-statement(like in your case -`else (answer == "Wrong") {)` ).

You can simply write this :

```
if (answer == "Right")  {
      switch(random_number)   {
           ...
      }
else {
      switch(random_number)   {
           ...
      }
}
```

It's means if your answer is not equal to `Right`, it always go to else statement.

OR

If you want to check for more conditions, use `else if(){}` statements.

```
if (answer == "Right")  {
      switch(random_number)   {
           ...
      }
else if (answer == "Wrong") {
      switch(random_number)   {
           ...
      }
}
```

[Read this](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp)